# Does Insight.Database inherit [Schema] annotations?

Tags: inheritance, insight.database

So I thought I'd try something a bit clever/stupid in my datalayer.  I'm using Jon Wagner's Insight.Database but most of my tables have a set of CRUD operations.  So I figured, why not do this :

```
public interface IDataInterface<T>
{
    Task<T> SelectAsync(int id);

    Task<IEnumerable<T>> SelectAsync();

    Task<int> UpsertAsync(T obj);

    Task<bool> UpsertManyAsync(IEnumerable<T> list);

    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(int id);

    Task<bool> DeleteManyAsync(IEnumerable<T> list);
}
```

and then I thought I could do something like this :

```
[Sql(Schema  = "Clients")]
public interface IClientDataInterface : IDataInterface<Client>
{

}
```

with all my stored procedures relating to the Clients table in a Clients schema.

However, this doesn't work and poking through the InnerExceptions until I finally  hit paydirt, I got the following error -

> InnerException = {"The stored procedure 'Select' doesn't exist."}

Even though Clients.Select definitely exists.

This indicates to me that the base interface (which has no [Sql] annotation) has a default of [Sql(Schema="dbo")] which is inherited and overrides any later annotation.

Is this right?  Is there a way to disable the base Schema if it it's right?  If not, what's going on?

Comment: just to clarify, I also get  {"The stored procedure 'Upsert' doesn't exist."} so it's not a reserved word thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit late getting back to this, but...

Nope.  Insight doesn't inherit [Sql] annotations.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Interface)]
```

I guess this is just one of those nice little tricks that won't work the way we all wish it would.